# Array Looping and Counting String Occurrences PHP

Tags: php

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

From the following array I want to count the the number of times "Friday" occurs.

```
Array ( 
[404979509517702] => Array ( 
    [0] => 235 
    [1] => 04:10,Friday 
) 
[404045862944400] => Array ( 
    [0] => 192 
    [1] => 23:52,Wednesday 
) 
[20403274909688162] => Array ( 
    [0] => 186 
    [1] => 22:21,Tuesday 
) 
[202735273075459] => Array ( 
    [0] => 336 
    [1] => 04:29,Tuesday 
) 
[652948031457462] => Array ( 
    [0] => 410 
    [1] => 06:22,Monday 
) 
[2606749954978] => Array ( 
    [0] => 312 
    [1] => 05:01,Saturday 
) 
[755318061725] => Array ( 
    [0] => 384 
    [1] => 04:51,Friday 
)
)
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
$friday = array();
foreach ($the_array as $friday){
    $the_array = explode(',', $friday[1]);

    $the_array[$the_array [1]] += ($friday[1]);
}

print_r($friday);
```

This way, I get the wrong number of "Friday" occurrences.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong or if there is a more elegant solution to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like the following if all you want to do is count occurrences:

```
$friday_count = 0;
foreach($the_array as $record) {
    // Search for "Friday"
    if(stristr($record[1],'Friday') !== false) {
        $friday_count++;    // increment count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$fridayCount = 0;
foreach ($the_array as $friday){
    $friArr = explode(',', $friday[1]);
    if($friArr[1] == "Friday") {
      $fridayCount++;
    }
}

echo ($fridayCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

The code should be:

```
$fridayCount = 0;

foreach ($the_array as $friday){
    if(strrpos($friday[1], 'Friday') !== false) {
       $fridayCount++;
    }
}

echo $fridayCount;
```

Comment: Line 4: `if(strrpos($friday[1], 'Friday') !== false) {`

Comment: Just tested your code (with ' in line 4), works fine! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be complicating this unnecessarily. You should be able to test for `'Friday'` and increment a counter (`$friday`, here) as follows:

```
$friday = 0;
foreach ($the_array as $element){
  if (array_pop(explode(',', $element[1])) == 'Friday') {
    $friday++;
  }
}

echo $friday;
```

Comment: Note that I'm not trimming any trailing spaces after `exploding` the day off of `$element[1]`--if that's a concern, you may need to wrap a `trim` in there before testing `== 'Friday'`

Comment: Hi @rjz, thanks for your answer. I tried implementing your code but when printing it I get "0". Any ideas why that happens? Trailing spaces won't be a concern but thanks for the good thought!

Comment: You are comparing array with string on line 3.

Comment: Thanks! Saw that `[1]` in there and called it good--should be better now.

Answer (score -2):

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($the_array as $friday){
  if (explode(',', $friday[1]) == 'Friday') {
    $cnt++;
  }
}
echo $cnt;
```